# Matching part of a URI

Tags: c#, api, uri

I'm writing an API in C# and was wondering if there is a way to perform a UriTemplateMatch on only part of a URI (ignoring query parameters/paths).

The reason I ask is because I have a parent HttpHandler class which delegates the request to the appropriate Handler for the request, for example:

```
// Parent templates
var playerTemplate = new UriTemplate("/v1/player/");
var gameTemplate   = new UriTemplate("/v1/games/");
```

But a request may come in that looks like:

```
http://server.com/v1/games/EU?played=today
```

My handler method currently performs a check like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
{
    UriTemplateMatch res = null;
    HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
    Uri requestedUri = new Uri(prefix + context.Request.RawUrl);

    // Check if the template matches, if it did then delegate context to Game Handler
    res = playerTemplate.Match(prefix, requestedUri);
    if (res != null)
        ASGameHandler.ProcessRequest(context);

    // Other templates are matched below
    ...
}
```

But currently it will obviously be null if a URI with query parameters is passed. How can I extract only the URI component held in the template to perform the match before delegating to the child handler?

Comment: Do you want something like String.Contains() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: I was wondering that myself - my lecturer at University said there are benefits for using UriTemplateMatching but I don't see what it achieves in comparison to a simple String comparison

Comment: I've just read the UriTemplate class on MSDN and it looks like you can do a lot more compared to String.Contains(). You can spin up something that does wildcard comparisons/parameter matching. Even though String.Contains() may be easier to implement, it's not every day that you can use the UriTemplate class.

Comment: Thanks for your time @mathemats I appreciate it. I'll give the class a more thorough read tomorrow